# Creating Single EXE File which includes Multiple EXE Files

Tags: c#, database, winforms, deployment, setup-deployment

I'am Working On windows forms application now i want to create single EXE File that includes my application EXE and also the prerequisites for my application.
i.e
my application has .net framework and sql sever express 2008 as prerequisites.now i want to install .net framework followed by sql sever followed by my application all the exe's need to package in single EXE file(sql server need to install only after successful instalation of .net framework).
please help how can i achieve this.
thanks

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a windows installer (which is in the VS Templates).  But last I checked you could not deploy .Net framework from your custom installer.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: It will probably be a very large .exe file. Why don't you use an installer? Like nullsoft installer: [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)

Comment: Or innosetup is good too

Answer (score 0):

I have used this in the past to install my prerequisites.

http://dblock.github.io/dotnetinstaller/